# Set a percentage discount to Local pickup shipping method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I have a WordPress site which uses WooCommerce plugin. I would like to offer buyer 5% reduction from cart total if they select local pickup as a shipping method.

I already tried **- 5 * [qty]** and it doesn't seem to be working.

I also tried -0.95 * [cost] with no luck

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using WooCommerce 3 and achieved the above result by writing a function inside the function.php of active theme.

```
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) {
  $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
  $chosen_shipping_no_ajax = $chosen_methods[0];
  if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping_no_ajax, 'local_pickup' ) ) {

    // Define the discount percentage
    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.05;
    // Add your discount note to cart
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Collection discount applied', 'yourtext-domain' ) , -$discount );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line');
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain this function please? I am trying to apply it to a website but find it difficult to read

Comment: To add taxation to the fee, use true as the add_fee's third parameter.
`$cart->add_fee( __( 'Collection discount applied', 'yourtext-domain' ) , -$discount, true );`

Comment: Can you do the same "discount logic" but only for certain category , for example:
-10% discount only to products from "category A" if local pick-up is selected as "shipping method"

Answer (score 3):

> The problem with  the **fee API** is that **it always apply Taxes for negative fee** (Discount) and don't care about existing coupons discounts.

The code below, will set a defined **discount percentage In the shipping method "Local pickup" itself.**

You will need to set a reference shipping cost **with a simple initial cost** instead of your formula. It can be for example `10`, and will be replaced by the code discount.

> You may have to "Enable debug mode" in general shipping settings under "Shipping options" tab, to disable temporarily shipping caches.

The code *(where you will set your discount percentage)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'local_pickup_percentage_discount', 12, 2);
function local_pickup_percentage_discount( $rates, $package ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    // HERE define the discount percentage
    $percentage = 5; // 5%
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    // Loop through the shipping taxes array
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        $has_taxes = false;
        // Targetting "flat rate"
        if( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ){
            // Add the Percentage to the label name (otional
            $rates[$rate_key]->label .= ' ( - ' . $percentage . '% )';
            // Get the initial cost
            $initial_cost = $new_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
            // Calculate new cost
            $new_cost = -$subtotal * $percentage / 100;
            // Set the new cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = [];
            // Loop through the shipping taxes array (as they can be many)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                    // Get the initial tax cost
                    $initial_tax_cost = $new_tax_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key];
                    // Get the tax rate conversion
                    $tax_rate    = $initial_tax_cost / $initial_cost;
                    // Set the new tax cost
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                    $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Don't forget to disable "Enable debug mode" option in shipping settings.

[image]

Comment: At the moment the VAT/Tax is being calculated from the original subtotal (e.g. 20% of 100 = 20), and the VAT is not recalculating after discount is applied. I don't know much about tax, but surely the VAT should be recalculated after user select local pickup.

Comment: This causes a negative shipping total which is causing the order to fail. Is there a way around this failure?