# Percentage discount on shipping based on order total in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I'm trying to find a way through a plugin or via functions.php on how to discount the shipping only by 50% if the order is between £25 and £50.

I am using "[Set a percentage discount to Local pickup shipping method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180282/11987538)
" which discounts based on shipping method but I want it to discount all shipping methods as we have many and it doesn't have a rule for minimum order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could use the `woocommerce_package_rates` hook
- This will give a discount to the shipping by 50% if the order is between £25 and £50.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    /* Settings */
    $min = 25;
    $max = 50;
    $discount_percent = 50;

    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // Condition
    if ( $cart_total >= $min && $cart_total <= $max ) {
        // (Multiple)
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Get rate cost            
            $cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
            
            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $cost - ( ( $cost * $discount_percent ) / 100 );
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: needed to clear my cart cache and yes it worked now